# Regex: Not the beginning of a line?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string like this:    `-----------    243f,33f----`

Now I want to remove all the `-` chars except the first `-`, the `,` and the numbers. The result should be -243,33. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you use a specific language?

Comment: How would the result look in your example?

Comment: Do you want to remove or keep the comma ?

Comment: I'm afraid, you're not very specific about your intention. Removing everything except for the first `-` and `,` would give you `-,` and you can hardcode that ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Your question still isn't very clear, but this yields the output you want:

```
'----------- 243f,33f----'.replace(/(?!^-)[^\d,]+/g, '')
```

The regex matches one or more of any character except digits or commas, after making sure the first character isn't a hyphen at the beginning of the string.

**EDIT:** To those who came up with regexes using `(?<!^)` and then withdrew them because JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, that wasn't necessary.  I know there were other problems with those answers, but for the purpose of matching "not the beginning of the string", `(?!^)` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`'----------- 243f,33f----'.replace(/[^-0123456789,]/g, '').replace(/^-/, 'x').replace(/-/g, '').replace(/x/, '-')`

output: `'-243,33'`

Comment: This will add a dash at the begining even if there are none in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?:(^-)|[^\d,\r\n])
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v9bm)

Its a bit more difficult since Javascript does not support look behinds. So if there is a `-` at the start of the line it will be replaced by itself, for the other matches `$1` is empty so replaced with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

replace the substring from second character ala

```
string.charAt(0) + string.substring(1).replace("-","");
```

but i don't know if the syntax is correct

EDIT:

oh if you want to remove the f's too you can remove any nondigit and non-comma:

```
string.charAt(0) + string.substring(1).replace("[^0-9,]","");
```